# Style of programming templates

Tags: c++, templates

If having an option, which one would you choose?

```
template<class CheckEveryNode<true>>
struct X;

or 

template<bool CheckEveryNode>
struct X;
```

That isn't really obvious from a designers perspective, on one side we have readability in the actual code:

```
//taking first approach
//somewhere in the code
X<CheckEveryNode<false>> x;
```

on the second side there is much more to type and someone would prefer:

```
//taking second approach
//somewhere in the code
X<false> x;//but here we don't really see immediately what the false means.
```

So, looking forward to your opinions/suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Often dabbling in metaprogramming, I can only recommend a "verbose" approach, but I don't quite like the first approach you propose.

Ideally, when using Policies, you don't just pass a flag, you pass a Policy object, which will allow the user to customize it at will, rather than relying on your own predefined values.

For example:

```
struct NodeCheckerTag {};

struct CheckEveryNode {
  typedef NodeCheckerTag PolicyTag;
  void check(List const& list);
};

struct CheckFirstNode {
  typedef NodeCheckerTag PolicyTag;
  void check(List const& list);
};

template <typename Rand>
struct CheckSomeNodes {
  typedef NodeCheckerTag PolicyTag;
  CheckSomeNodes(Rand rand): _rand(rand) {}
  void check(List const& list);
  Rand _rand;
};
```

Your class should thus allow the user to choose which policy to elect:

```
template <typename NodeChecker>
class X: NodeChecker // allow stateful implementation but let EBO kick in
{
};
```

The `PolicyTag` is for the presence of several policies:

```
template <typename NodeChecker, typename NodeAllocator, typename NodeNotifier>
class X;
```

You should normally provide sensible defaults, but then there is always the case of *I want to customize just the last!*, by switching to a variadic template, you can get that:

```
template <typename Tag, typename Default, typename... Policies>
struct PolicySelector
{
  typedef /**/ type;
};

template <typename... Policies>
class X: Policies...
{
  typedef typename PolicySelector<NodeCheckerTag, CheckNoNode,
    Policies...>::type NodeCheckerPolicy;
  typedef typename PolicySelector<NodeAllocatorTag, StdAllocator,
    Policies...>::type NodeAllocatorPolicy;
  ...
};
```

Note that by inheriting from the policies, the selection might be unnecessary if you only care about invoking some functions. It's only necessary if you need inner typedefs hidden in the policies as those should be explicitly typedef'd in the derived class (X here).

Comment: @Natthieu Thank you for (elaborating example). The only thing I was asking here is which way one should do it - by policies even though they may be cumbersome to write or by naked - "built-ins". Nothing else. But thank you for your (such elaborate) answer.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
template<class CheckEveryNode<true>>
struct X;
```

Would be wrong, it should be

```
template<template<bool> CheckEveryNode>
struct X{};
```

which would need you either to specialize on either true or false condition:

```
// above is true case, below is false case
template<>
struct X<CheckEveryNode<false> >{};
```

Or use partial specialization in the following way:

```
template<class CheckEveryNode>
struct X;

template<bool B>
struct X<CheckEveryNode<B> >{
  // real implementation
};
```

Aside from that, the second one is easier to implement and also easier to read, because it is "as expected". When you supply a template argument, you know what it is for, no need for an extra struct.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is what happens when you have multiple policies, and you don't know what the various boolean values mean, you could eliminate the booleans all together and use tags.

```
struct CheckEvery { };
struct CheckNone { };

template<typename Check> struct Thingy;
template<> Thingy<CheckEvery> { ... };
template<> Thingy<CheckNone> { ... };
```

Or you can let the policies dictate the work to be done, rather than specialize.

```
struct CheckEvery { bool shouldCheck(int) { return true; } };
struct CheckNone { bool shouldCheck(int) { return false; } };
struct CheckOdds { bool shouldCheck(int i) { return i % 2; } };

template<typename Checker> struct Thingy {
  Checker checker;
  void someFunction(int i) { if(checker.shouldCheck(i)) check(i); }
};
```

The example isn't well fleshed out, but it gives you the idea.  You'd probably want to provide a `Checker` object to the `Thingy` constructor, for instance.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I posted example with boolean values just as an "example". I'm interested here about opinion of users how they percieve policies vs "naked" types.

Comment: You did ask for suggestions, these are mine.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach looks cumbersome. I would go for the second one in the absence of compelling rationale for the first one. As for readability, the second one is readable. In fact, first one reduces readability because of its hotchpotch syntax.

Comment: @Nawaz bear in mind that there will/maybe more than one "policy" and then if you choosen first one you would have X<false,true,false,false,true> and this isn't really that obvious to more elaborate but very readable. And old maxim says "Computer programs are read by computers just few times but by people hundreds if not thousands."

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: So tell me what do you find more readable: `X<false,true,false,false,true>` OR `X<A_type<false>,B_type<true>,C_type<false>,D_type<false>,E_type<true>>`?

Comment: @Nawaz there is also an art of naming types, you know.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I'm not talking about the type names, rather just imagine you see so many types within a type as type arguments to it, and each type argument in turns has either `true` or `false` as value argument. That surely looks cumbersome. It looks exactly like when compiler generates error for template code. Do you really want to see them when coding? Do you really find it readable?

Comment: @Nawaz and who said that there always be only true or false (bool)?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Whatever it is, do you find this `values within inner_types within outer_type` readable?

Answer (score 0):

I like the second one as well.  My philosophy would be, why create an extra type if you don't have to?